# looping through pages from JSON request

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm just testing some JSON requests.
When calling 
I only get 25 results back in JSON-stream of 29 results total.
How do I get the othes results ?

05.03.2020 10:03:35 total_results: 29
05.03.2020 10:03:35 current_page: 1
05.03.2020 10:03:35 per_page: 25
05.03.2020 10:03:35 total_pages: 2
05.03.2020 10:03:35 result-IDs via '.Children':
05.03.2020 10:03:35 714730998338
05.03.2020 10:03:35 867663179795
...
05.03.2020 10:03:35 869834637465
05.03.2020 10:03:35 resultIDs via 'jsonObject.SelectTokens('results[*].id':
05.03.2020 10:03:35 714730998338
05.03.2020 10:03:35 867663179795
...
05.03.2020 10:03:35 869834637465

[returned JSON Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB76T.png)

```
    Dim url As String = "Http://imvdb.com/api/v1/search/videos?q=Rammstein+Herzeleid"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.UserAgent = "TEST"
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim Stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
    Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Stream)
    Dim Data As String
    Data = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
    StreamReader.Close()

    Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(Data)
    Dim bError As Boolean
    Dim sTMP As String
    Dim myToken As JToken
    Dim myCol As IEnumerable

    myToken = jsonObject.SelectToken("total_results", bError)
    If Not bError Then LOGtextAdd("total_results: " & myToken.ToString)
    myToken = jsonObject.SelectToken("current_page", bError)
    If Not bError Then LOGtextAdd("current_page: " & myToken.ToString)
    myToken = jsonObject.SelectToken("per_page", bError)
    If Not bError Then LOGtextAdd("per_page: " & myToken.ToString)
    myToken = jsonObject.SelectToken("total_pages", bError)
    If Not bError Then LOGtextAdd("total_pages: " & myToken.ToString)

    LOGtextAdd("result-IDs via '.Children':")
    myToken = jsonObject.SelectToken("results", bError)
    For Each x In myToken.Children
        sTMP = x.SelectToken("id", bError).ToString
        If Not bError Then LOGtextAdd(x.SelectToken("id").ToString)
    Next

    LOGtextAdd("resultIDs via 'jsonObject.SelectTokens('results[*].id':")
    myCol = jsonObject.SelectTokens("results[*].id", bError)
    For Each myToken In myCol
        LOGtextAdd(myToken.ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: The API supports a `per_page` parameter, where the maximum allowed is `50`. And/or a `page` parameter, where you specify the Page number. So you probably want to query the results, see whether you have more pages, and query the other pages in a loop. The API call can be, i.e., `https://imvdb.com/api/v1/search/videos?q=Rammstein+Herzeleid&per_page=50` or `https://imvdb.com/api/v1/search/videos?q=Rammstein+Herzeleid&page=2`

Comment: I already had read this somewhere but it did not work.  Now I added the page-option and it worked fine ... don't know why. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You need a loop anyway. Unless you just want a maximum of 50 results (with, e.g., `Led-Zeppelin+Stairway-to-Heaven` you have `2747` video clips :). be aware that, when no Image links are available, the server returns an empty array instead of a `JObject`.